# display the array value in various cell

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to display the name and date for specific requirements. for eg requirement oracle DBA has 3 submittal on various dates.table 'requirement' have field as e_id and req_id.

2nd table 'submittal' has req_id, submittal and date fields
I want to display submittal in one column and date in another column based on requirement.

[image]

I tried to display with array values

```
 $sub="select a.*,b.c_name from requirement as a,client as b where a.c_id=b.c_id and e_id='2'";
 $sub1=mysql_query($sub);

 while($sfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sub1))
 {
     echo '<tr>';
     $req_id=$sfet['req_id'];
     echo '<td>'.$sfet['c_name'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$sfet['title'].'</td>';
     $was="select * from resume where req_id='$req_id'";
     $was1=mysql_query($was);

     while($wfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($was1))
     {
         $array[] = $wfet;
     }

     echo '<td>';
     echo $array[]['username'];
     echo '</td>';

     echo '<td>';
     echo $array[]['date'];
     echo '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as follows:

```
while($sfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sub1))
{
     echo '<tr>';
     $req_id=$sfet['req_id'];
     echo '<td>'.$sfet['c_name'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$sfet['title'].'</td>';
     $was="select * from resume where req_id='$req_id'";
     $was1=mysql_query($was);

     $username = $date = [];
     while($wfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($was1))
     {
         $username[] = $wfet['username'];
         $date[] = $wfet['date'];
     }

     echo '<td>';
     echo implode('<br>',$username);
     echo '</td>';

     echo '<td>';
     echo implode('<br>',$date);
     echo '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
```

**EDIT:**
even better solution would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` as follows:

```
$sub = "SELECT a.*, b.c_name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.username ORDER BY c.date SEPARATOR '<br>') AS g_username,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.date ORDER BY c.date SEPARATOR '<br>') AS g_date 
    FROM requirement as a 
    JOIN client as b ON a.c_id=b.c_id 
    JOIN resume c ON a.req_id=c.req_id GROUP BY a.req_id";

$sub1=mysql_query($sub);
while($sfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sub1))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $req_id=$sfet['req_id'];
    echo '<td>'.$sfet['c_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$sfet['title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$sfet['g_username'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$sfet['g_date'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```